# Email to mail group - Outlook Mail API

Tags: android, outlook, ms-office, office365api, office365-restapi

I need to send via email a pin from an android app to a mail group using Outlook Mail REST API.
How can I achieve this? I can't find anything about groups on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations).

I want to avoid to store the admin users in a static config file and POST a request to "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail" with a JSON content like:

```
{
  "Message": {
    "Subject": "ADMIN PIN FOR ANDROID APP",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Text",
      "Content": "The secret pin is: 12345"
    },
    "ToRecipients": [ // ( list generated from config file )
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "user1@company.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "user2@company.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by contacts group, is it meaning mail group?

Comment: @JeffreyChen-MSFT yes thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an email group , you will have a email address target to this group(you could find the address in the property of the group) . With the address, you could call Outlook Mail REST API to send your message :
[Create and send messages via Outlook Mail REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createandsendmessages)

In addition, the group only accepts messages from people in its organization or on its allowed senders list. If you cannot send the email , you could ask the owner of the group to grant you permission to send to it, and then try again .